# Updating records in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a sample update page for the student. It's just simple, but it doesn't save to the database. I'm new to PHP and in this page, it retrieves the data from the database and displays on the text boxes but when I save it, it redirects me to the correct page but my data is gone...

```
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'testing';

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$server", "$user", "$pass")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db")or die("cannot select DB");

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $name = $_POST["name"][$username];
    $address = $_POST["address"][$username];
    $age = $_POST["age"][$username];
    $cellno = $_POST["cellno"][$username];
    $email = $_POST["email"][$username];

    mysql_query ("UPDATE `users_info` SET `name` ='$name', `address` ='$address',`age` ='$age', `cellno` ='$cellno' , `email` ='$email' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."' ") or die(mysql_error()); 

    header("Location: myprofile.php");  
}
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM users_info WHERE username= '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."' ";
        $res= mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows($res) >0) {
        echo '<form method="post">';
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
            echo 'Username:'. $row['username'].'</p> ';
            echo 'Name: <input type="text" name="name['.$row["username"].']" value="'. $row['name'].'"></p> ';
            echo 'Address: <input type="text" name="address['.$row["username"].']" value="'. $row['address'].'"></p> ';
            echo 'Age: <input type="text" name="age['.$row["username"].']" value="'. $row['age'].'"></p> ';
            echo 'Phone: <input type="text" name="cellno['.$row["username"].']" value="'. $row['cellno'].'"></p> ';
            echo 'Email: <input type="text" name="email['.$row["username"].']" value="'. $row['email'].'"></p> ';
        }

        echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">';
        echo '</form>';

    }
```

?>

i already have a `session_start();` at this page.

Comment: make sure you have set the value in session `$_SESSION['user']['username']`, for debugging it just print and check the session before submitting with `print_r($_SESSION);`

Comment: yes jogesh_pi, i have `$_SESSION['user']['username']`

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "UPDATE `users_info` SET `name` ='$name', `address` ='$address',`age` ='$age', `cellno` ='$cellno' , `email` ='$email' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."'";

echo $query;
```

Then check out the output. Or use instead of echo $query:

```
mysql_query($query); 
echo mysql_error();
```

Update 2 for full code:

```
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'testing';

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$server", "$user", "$pass")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db")or die("cannot select DB");

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $name = $_POST["name"][$username];
    $address = $_POST["address"][$username];
    $age = $_POST["age"][$username];
    $cellno = $_POST["cellno"][$username];
    $email = $_POST["email"][$username];

   $query = "UPDATE `users_info` SET `name` ='$name', `address` ='$address',`age` ='$age', `cellno` ='$cellno' , `email` ='$email' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."'";

    die($query);

    //header("Location: myprofile.php");  
}
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM users_info WHERE username= '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."' ";
        $res= mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows($res) >0) {
        echo '<form method="post">';
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
            echo 'Username:'. $row['username'].'</p> ';
            echo 'Name: <input type="text" name="name['.$row["username"].']" value="'. $row['name'].'"></p> ';
            echo 'Address: <input type="text" name="address['.$row["username"].']" value="'. $row['address'].'"></p> ';
            echo 'Age: <input type="text" name="age['.$row["username"].']" value="'. $row['age'].'"></p> ';
            echo 'Phone: <input type="text" name="cellno['.$row["username"].']" value="'. $row['cellno'].'"></p> ';
            echo 'Email: <input type="text" name="email['.$row["username"].']" value="'. $row['email'].'"></p> ';
        }

        echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">';
        echo '</form>';

    }
```

Update 3:

You had some  db connection problems!
Here is the fixed one:

```
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'testing';

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass );
mysql_select_db($db);
```

Comment: Hello, i've tried it but still, it redirects me to the correct page but the data that i've been inputed is not saving

Comment: I updated the code. I put die($query) in it, so you can see the result before it relocates you.

Comment: hello, it redirects me to the correct page again, but it shows an error "Undefined index: root" what does it mean?

Comment: mysql_connect($server,$user, $pass);

Change this line to $server $user and $pass ,like i wrote. and check it out. it did not connected to sql.

Also 
mysql_select_db($db);

Comment: it displays `UPDATE `users_info` SET `name` ='Array', `address` ='Array',`age` ='Array', `cellno` ='Array' , `email` ='Array' WHERE username = '0510-0410-10439'`  it displays the sql query.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass)or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db($db)or die("cannot select DB");
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{

$name = $_POST["name[$username]"];
$address = $_POST["address[$username]"];
$age = $_POST["age[$username]"];
$cellno = $_POST["cellno[$username]"];
$email = $_POST["email[$username]"];

 mysql_query ("UPDATE `users_info` SET `name` ='$name', `address` ='$address',`age` ='$age', `cellno` ='$cellno' , `email` ='$email' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."' ") or die(mysql_error()); 

    header("Location: myprofile.php");  
}
```

Comment: @user3389082: did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your $username variable is set when reading in you $_POST variables. Is it inserting empty rows?
Try changing

```
$name = $_POST["name"][$username];
```

to

```
$name = $_POST["name"][$_SESSION['user']['username']];
```

Comment: hello tcshields, i've tried it, it redirects me to the correct page, but it displays the sql query with the values i've inputted on the text boxes.

Comment: your query has the values but it's still not updating the record?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried another answer for this and it's working properly.

```
<?php
// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
    require("common.php"); 

    // At the top of the page we check to see whether the user is logged in or not 
    if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
    { 
        // If they are not, we redirect them to the login page. 
        header("Location: login.php"); 

        // Remember that this die statement is absolutely critical.  Without it, 
        // people can view your members-only content without logging in. 
        die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
    } 

    // Everything below this point in the file is secured by the login system 

    // We can display the user's username to them by reading it from the session array.  Remember that because 
    // a username is user submitted content we must use htmlentities on it before displaying it to the user.
    // Database Variables (edit with your own server information)
        $server = 'localhost';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = '';
        $db = 'testing';

        // Connect to server and select databse.
        mysql_connect("$server", "$user", "$pass")or die("cannot connect"); 
        mysql_select_db("$db")or die("cannot select DB");


    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_info WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."'");
    $test = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if (!$result) 
        {
        die("Error: Data not found..");
        }
                $name = $test['name'];
                $address = $test['address'];
                $age = $test['age'];
                $cellno = $test['cellno'];
                $email = $test['email'];


if(isset($_POST['save']))
{   
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $cellno = $_POST['cellno'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    mysql_query("UPDATE `users_info` SET `name` ='$name', `address` ='$address',`age` ='$age', `cellno` ='$cellno' , `email` ='$email' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."'");

    header("Location: myprofile.php");          
}
?>
```

There you go. Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.